# Disable plugin for administrator

Tags: plugins, admin, user-roles

I need to disable a specific plugin for administrators.

I found this piece of code that should do the trick, but it's not working for me. I don't really know much about PHP so I don't know how to fix it.

```
add_filter( 'option_active_plugins', 'disable_logged_in_plugin' );

function disable_logged_in_plugin( $plugins ) {

    // The 'option_active_plugins' hook occurs before any user information get generated,
    // so we need to require this file early to be able to check for logged in status
    require (ABSPATH . WPINC . '/pluggable.php');

    if ( current_user_can('administrator') ) {

        // Use the plugin folder and main file name here.
        // is used here as an example
           $plugins_not_needed = array ( 'no-right-click-images-plugin/no-right-click-images-plugin.php' );
            foreach ( $plugins_not_needed as $plugin ) {
                $key = array_search( $plugin, $plugins );
                if ( false !== $key ) {
                    unset( $plugins[ $key ] );
                }
            }
        }

        return $plugins;
    }
```

As Castiblanco requested, here is my theme's functions.php in pastebin: https://pastebin.com/qZwSzmgh

"code" and "pre" weren't working properly here.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested your code and it works, so it seems one of the two following things.

You are placing the code in the wrong place, make sure you put that code at the bottom of the `functions.php` file of your theme. Or maybe the `functions.php` file of your theme is having problems, in which case you could share it with us by posting its content editing your question.

---

It seems alright, do this:

Open your `wp-config.php` and add these lines:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
```

Let me know what it shows after.

Comment: I just added my functions.php code.

Comment: Answer updated, let me know.

Comment: It shows some notices about the theme: https://pastebin.com/TJU1J2YF  
  
  
  
Only when I access the home page, other pages and blog posts show nothing.